# iPhone Push Notification server wirtting in C# to run on windows

Tags: iphone, .net, windows, notifications, push

I want a push notification service to run on windows written using C#. Is it possible any guide lines?

Comment: Friend, I see that you're new here, but you are going to want to put quite a bit more effort into the question. People aren't going to write an entire subsystem for you here -- get something started on your own and if you have issues specifically, post them here with code snippets and very specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple google search showed me this [tutorial](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/) which seems cover everything.